# Python: unable to authenticate using requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

I'm having some trouble authenticating myself into the PJ website using the Python requests module. My code is as follows:

```
import requests 

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.auth = ("my_email", "my_password")
    r = s.get( "https://www.example.com/")
```

However, I receive a response which indicates that I haven't logged in. Is it simply impossible to do this? Am I missing something (e.g. CSRF token)?

EDIT: I did some poking around to see what happens when I manually log in. You can see a screengrab of the request my browser sends here: [PJ Login Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlFLN.png)

Comment: You probably need to POST to a login endpoint - I'd be surprised if papajohns just used basic http authentication... (which means you need to look at the page source - identify the form, the target url and construct the appropriate request to emulate the login)

Comment: @JonClements The image in my edit shows the form data (i.e. target url, user, pass), however, I am little lost in figuring out what type of authentication to use. Any advice?

Comment: You generally don't use any... you make a suitable POST request with your username/password to the right place with a requests.Session() as you are, then you'll probably get a cookie back, so that re-using the session to make further requests means you're already logged in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, following Jon's guidance:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    payload = {'user':'my_email','pass':'my_password', 'target':'/order/menu'}
    r = s.post( "https://www.example.com/order/signin", data=payload)
```

I had already figured out the correct payload from the request (using the screengrab in my edit above), but I was sending it to the wrong location (i.e. the home page instead of the user login page).

Answer (score 0):

Try with Post Method which is not sent in plaintext if using http.

With `https` BOTH `GET` and `POST` are sent securely and not in plaintext.

```
import requests 

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.auth = ("my_email", "my_password")
    r = s.post( "https://www.papajohns.com/")


>>> r
>>> <Response [200]>
```

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately, it gives me the same result as using a GET request.

Comment: A get method over https is not sent in plaintext either.